# Fish shell run a command with parenthesis in arguments

Tags: fish

I am attempting to run the command

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf yadif,format=yuv420p -force_key_frames expr:gte(t\,n_forced/2) -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -bf 2 -c:a aac -q:a 1 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -use_editlist 0 -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

as mentioned [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/24481/26801). However, the issue is the argument `expr:gte(t\,n_forced/2)` contains parenthesis and fish shell will interpret `t\,n_forced/2` as a commmand. Is there any way to run this in fish shell instead of needing to make a seperate bash script?

Note, I cannot wrap with single quotes as I get the following
[image: Missing ')' or too many args in 'gte(t\,n_forced/2)']

Comment: does'nt `"expr:gte(t\,n_forced/2)"` work ?

Comment: @ymonad unfortunately not. Look at the updated question.

Comment: maybe you don't need ``\``. try `"expr:gte(t,n_forced/2)"`

Comment: Yes, this fixed it. Think I should delete the question? Or just reword it?

Comment: I think you should add your own answer and then accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surrounding the argument `expr:gte(t\,n_forced/2)` in single quotes and removing the backslash in `\,` fixed the problem.

The resulting argument is `'expr:gte(t\n_forced/2)'`.